# Characteristic Polynomial of Block matrix or determinant of bloack matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, block-matrices, characteristic-polynomial

Let $J$ be all-one matrix ( matrix with all entries 1) and $I$ be an identity matrix. Find the characteristic Polynomial or determinant of $n\times n$ matrix $M$.

$$M= \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
(J+(n-2)I)_{a\times a}&J_{a\times n-a}\\
J_{n-a\times a}&(2J+(2n-4-a)I)_{n-a\times n-a}
\end{array}
\right] $$

Comment: It can help to know which graph is involved. Can you give a bit more context?

Comment: The graph involved is $K_a \Delta (n-a) K_1 $, where $\Delta$ denotes join of a graph ( joining each vertex of $K_a$ with each vertex of $(n-a) K_1$).

Comment: @Zizu Do you have a reason to believe that there is a nice expression for the characteristic polynomial or determinant?

Answer (score 2):

We can write this matrix as $M = D + AA^T$, where
$$
D = \pmatrix{(n-2)I & 0\\0 & (2n - 4 - a) I},\quad A = \pmatrix{e_a & 0\\e_{n-a} & e_{n-a}}, \quad 
e_n = (1,\dots,1)^T \in \Bbb R^n.
$$

With the [W-A identity (AKA Sylvester's identity)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity), we have
$$
\det(D + AA^T) = \det(D) \det(I + D^{-1}AA^T) =
\det(D) \det(I_2 + A^TD^{-1}A).
$$
Compute
$$
A^T[D^{-1}A] = \pmatrix{e_a & 0\\e_{n-a} & e_{n-a}}^T\pmatrix{\frac 1{n-2}e_a & 0\\\frac{1}{2n - 4 - a}e_{n-a} & \frac 1{2n - 4 - a}{}e_{n-a}}\\
= \pmatrix{\frac{a}{n-2} + \frac{n-a}{2n-4-a} & \frac{n-a}{2n-4-a}\\
\frac{n-a}{2n-4-a} & \frac{n-a}{2n-4-a}},
$$
$\det(D) = (n-2)^a(2n - 4 - a)^{n-a}$, and proceed from there.

The characteristic polynomial can be computed in a similar fashion; we need only replace $D$ with
$$
D - \lambda I = \pmatrix{(n-2 - \lambda)I & 0\\0 & (2n - 4 - a - \lambda) I}.
$$